# Typescript/Javascript Promise not entered

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have the following Typescript code. I have a `promise` that I need to complete and return. However, the `promise` is not working as expected. Any advise is appreciated.

**chats.ts**

```
  private loadChats(): void {
      let promiseRefreshedLocalDatabase: Promise<any> = this.chatsStorageService.openDatabase();
      promiseRefreshedLocalDatabase.then((data) => {
        console.log('--> in chat promise: data '+data);
      });
  }
```

**chatsStorageService.ts**

```
public openDatabase(): Promise<any> {
    let promise: Promise<any> = new Promise<any>(resolve => {
        this.database = new SQLite();
        this.database.openDatabase({ name: "data.db", location: "default" }).then(() => {
            let promiseChats: Promise<Array<Chat>> = this.refreshChats();
            return promiseChats.then((chatsData) => {
                let promiseMessages: Promise<Array<Message>> = this.refreshMessages();
                return promiseMessages.then((messagesData) => {

                });
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("OPEN ERROR: ", error);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

**output**

I would expect:

> ```
> refreshChats
> refreshMessages
> --> in chat promise: data [object]
> ```

but only get from the calls to `this.refreshChats()` and `this.refreshChats()`:

> ```
> refreshChats
> refreshMessages
> ```

i.e. `console.log('--> in chat promise: data '+data);` is not executed.

Comment: Where is your `loadChats` call?

Comment: Oh, i see, it first calls `loadChats`

Comment: Yes that's right. It gets called from the constructor.

Comment: In your openDatabase():, you not calling the resolve, try putting resolve(messagesData);

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try....

Comment: Also your not letting your error cascade, in most cases that's not what you want, you will get the console.log message, but any method calling this will not get informed.

Comment: Thanks Keith, that (resolve(messagesData);) made it work now.  Noted about the errors, I will make the changes. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 0):

In your openDatabase():, you are not calling the resolve, try putting `resolve(messagesData);`

Comment: Please either ask the user to make the comment into an answer or make your answer community wiki.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13889845)

Comment: @Sherif Actually, it does.